# Postgre SQL + PHP return data with string type on fieldv int4

Tags: php, postgresql

So i hgave big problem. In my base i have field with type int4.
I do simply query like

```
SELECT * FROM "Cities"
```

And if i do `var_dump(pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC));` i can see that my field id (int4) like
**(string)**id. Why it's return all values like string?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference comes from the way the different PostgreSQL drivers present the extracted data from the database.
More specifically using only strings in some cases.

The fastest way to fix that is to use comparison that look like:
`($id == 5) // true` instead of
`($id === 5) // false`
assuming `$id="5";`

Maybe your driver also can be tuned to return not only strings, but integers as well.
If you provide driver specific info maybe somebody can help you more with the fine tuning of the driver.

In case you are using PDO, then those will help:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

The second line has nothing to do with the strings, but is recommended.

Comment: I am using codeigniter freamework. I don't think that there are problems with driver..

Comment: @user2051503 This is not a problem with the driver! This is actually the expected behavior. The thing is that you are expecting something else ...

Comment: So what i need to do? i need to manualy do intval() for any element?

Comment: First I will try the `ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES` trick and see if this helps. Otherwise what is your use case? Why `intval` is necessary?